# Translation help

Tags: translation, miracle, ezra-nechemya, yehoshua-joshua

Can someone please translate this word for word? Its Bnei Yisaschar mamrei elul.

This is the sefaria link:
https://www.sefaria.org/Bnei_Yissaschar%2C_Elul.1.17.1?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Bnei_Yisaschar,_Piotrkow_1883&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en

הנה הכובש כיבוש ראשון נקרא יהושע (לשון ישועה שהוא למעלה מן העשיה) כי נעשו לו ניסים שלא כדרך טבע העשיה. והכובש כיבוש ב' נקרא עזרא (לשון עזרה שהוא בעשיה) כי כיבושו היה בדרך טבע העשיה וכוונת רבנו זכרונו לברכה לפי זה ראויים היו ישראל לעשות להם נס בימי עזרא וכו' רצה לומר אלו היו ראויים לזה בודאי היה שם ראש הדור בלשון ישועה והיו נעשים להם ניסים שלא בטבע העשיה אבל להיות שלא זכו נקרא שם ראש הדור בלשון עזר ולא נעשה להם נס רק בטבע העשיה

Answer (score 0):

> Here the first conqueror is called Yehoshua-Joshua (the language of salvation which is above doing) because miracles were performed for him that were not in the nature of doing. And the conqueror of the second conquest is called Ezra (the language of help that he does) because his conquest was in the natural way of doing and the intention of our Rabbi of blessed memory was according to this Israel deserved to have a miracle done for them in the days of Ezra - which means to say that those who deserved it must have been the head of the generation in the language of "ישועה" - "salvation" and miracles were performed for them that were not in the nature of doing, but to be meritorious, we call them the heads of the generation in the expression of "עזר" - "helping" and a miracle was only performed through the natural means.

Comment: I apologise if I have offended anyone with my translation. It is basic derech eretz to perhaps provide a constructive comment than leave a nameless downvote...

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t have time to discuss it earlier. I’m certainly not offended by your translation, but I did think that it was not entirely accurate. A few specific points: 1) לשון עזרה שהוא בעשיה is I think referring to the category of עשיה vs the category of ישועה rather than Ezra’s specific actions. 2) אלו היו ראויים לזה I think is “ilu — if” rather than “eilu — these”.

Comment: 3) The follow through of the previous point is that the next part means that if they had in fact been deserving then their leader(‘s name) would have reflected the quality of ישועה rather than the quality of עשיה instead. 4) אבל להיות שלא זכו is the opposite side of the previous statement — that they were not in fact deserving and so their leader only reflected the quality of עזר/עשיה instead.

Comment: @Alex thanks for getting back to me I appreciate your comments - I'm out working on a job the whole day - feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The conqueror of the first conquest [of Israel], is called Yehoshua (the word for salvation, which is above asiyah*) because miracles were done to him that were not according to the way of the nature of this world.  And the conqueror of the second conquest was called Ezra (the word for "help: for he followed the natural order) because his conquest was in the way of the nature of action [of earth] and the intention of our rabbi OBM according to this, Israel deserved to have a miracle done to them in the days of Ezra, (just like by Joshua, if not for their sins) etc. That means to say if they were to have been worthy they would surely have called the head of the generation in the language of 'salvation' and miracles would be performed for them that were not in the nature of asiya (our natural order), but since they were v not worthy [for to their sins], the name of the head of the generation was called in the language of Ezer (help) and a miracle wasn't performed for them only in the nature of asiya.

- I'm not about to reveal any סוד. But there are four different "worlds" :
  אצילות, בריאה, יצירה ועשיה.
  Our world "עשיה" is the lowest and means we need to be active in order to bring about repairs.